# Is there a snazzy way of counting all the products in a store in Magento? getProduct() wants an id

Tags: magento

```
$product1 = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getProduct(42, $storeId);
```

Cannot be used as it requires I give the product id.
Also the category method wants a category id.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection');
$collection->addStoreFilter();
$total_products_in_store = $collection->getSize();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$storeId = 2;

/** @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addStoreFilter($storeId);

// Retrieve product count in collection
$size = $collection->count(); // or $collection->getSize()
```

Comment: When you call `->count()` on a collection Magento actually loads all products to the collection which involves some massive SQL queries. Using `->getSize()` instead (see my answer below which) just returns the number of results without loading the collection.

Comment: Not only massive SQL queries, but also memory usage which, if used improperly, can lead to that `Fatal error: Out of memory...` we've all grown to know and love.

Comment: Another note is that if you want to use not fixed store ID but the current active store the parameter of the `addStoreFilter()` have to be omitted.